# Curl throwing ‘Promise already completed’ error

Tags: javascript, curl, asynchronous, requirejs, labjs

I’m currently testing various asynchronous-resource-loaders to see which one I want to use. At the moment [**Curl**](https://github.com/unscriptable/curl) is throwing a ‘**Promise already completed**’ error…and their documentation says ‘this should never happen’.

I “suspect” I must to use a ‘define’ within each file being loaded (hope not). Further, their documentation says Curl can work with non-AMD javascript files. But...I am new to AMD and since [**Curl**](https://github.com/unscriptable/curl) is **far-faster** than the other ones I'm testing...I am willing to put some time into understanding this better.

**Lastly...**

Even though FireBug shows the errors...all the files STILL LOAD asynchronously! But, BECAUSE there are errors...the '**then**' portion of the code never gets called.

**So My Questions Are:**

- Do I have to update all the JavaScript file-objects to be contained in a 'define'? (...hope not)
- Can you see any other problem syntactically?

**The Head’s Code Looks Like This:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ///<summary>Configuration</summary>
    curl = { baseUrl: 'Includes/JavaScript/' };
</script>
<script src="Loaders/Curl/curl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onSuccess() {
    }
    function onError(ex) {
        //alert(ex);
    }

    require(["MooTools/Core/mootools-1.2.2-core-jm",
        "MooTools/mGeneral",
        "jQuery/Core/jquery-1.3.2",
        "jQuery/Core/jquery.tools.min",
        "jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.tmpl"])
        .then(onSuccess, onError);

    //require(["jQuery/TopUp/top_up-min"], null);

    require(["jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.dimensions",
        "jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jQuery.Color.Animations",
        "jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.corners.min",
        "jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.tipsy",
        "jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.numberformatter-1.1.0",
        "jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.tipsy"]);

    require(["general",
        "WindowCenter",
        "ThirdPartyPlugin/KeyBoardCapture",
        "ThirdPartyPlugin/bsn.AutoSuggest_2.1.3",
        "ee/8Ball",
        "ee/EE"]);
</script>
```

***Again...I'm sure it is caused by inexperience with AMD-styled code, but I still need help...so any is appreciated.***

Comment: heh. I hate it when I get an error that "should never happen". It seems to happen a lot more often than it should.  :-/

Comment: FYI: I prematurely marked the answer below as correct.  I am currently working with the author of Curl who has generously offered-up his help.  We will update the answer below once done and I'll re-mark it then

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you should wrap your modules in a `define()` or append a `define()` at the end of the file if those modules have no dependencies.  It seems, though, that those modules all depend on jQuery, if not other modules/files.

Since you're not using standard AMD `require()`/`define()` protocol, AMD is not really helping you with these modules.  Unless you plan to write your own modules using `define()`, then you could use just about any async loader.

That said, there is a way to make curl.js work with non-AMD modules/files.  Use the js! plugin.  Here's your first block of files translated to use the js! plugin (note I also added the ".js" ext back on which I like to do with non-modules):

```
// we load the core files first, then get the next block that depends on them
curl([
    "js!MooTools/Core/mootools-1.2.2-core-jm.js",
    "js!jQuery/Core/jquery-1.3.2.js"
]).next([
    "js!MooTools/mGeneral.js",
    "js!jQuery/Core/jquery.tools.min.js",
    "js!jQuery/ThirdPartyPlugIns/jquery.tmpl.js"
]).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

If any of those files within each array depend on each other, you can also use the !order suffix on them to ensure they wait for other files before executing/evaluating (be sure you're setting proper cache headers, though).  Actually, the !order suffix is the fastest method as long as there are no caching issues (mobile browsers add some additional constraints on file size).

Were there any other error messages?  Specifically, I would expect curl.js to throw at least one error besides just "Promise not completed".

Also, please check the Net tab (Firebug) or the Network tab (Chrome) to check that curl.js is looking in the correct location for the modules.

FWIW, I am planning to remove the alias `require` --> `curl`.  The reason is that the global `require` function is non-standard (and explicitly not standardized in the AMD proposal).  I suggest you use `curl()` instead of `require()`.

curl.js also allows it's top-level api to be aliased explicitly via the "apiName" config param if you really, really want to use the name "require". :)

```
<script>curl = { apiName: "require" }; </script>
<script src="path/to/curl.js"></script>
<script>require(["some/modules"]).then(success, failure);</script>
```

More FWIW: the standard `require` is typically only needed in a module and can be requested by including it as a dependency:

```
define(["require"], function (require) {
    require(["another/module"], function (another) {
        // use another module here
    });
});
```

-- John

Comment: FYI: The current set of downloadable code seems to contains no method for "next".  And I don't see a definition in any file in the extension nor plugin directories.

Comment: FYI: The current set of downloadable code "seems" to contains no support for the '!order' suffix.  And I don't see a definition in any file in the extension nor plugin directories.  And it breaks upon use.

Comment: Doh! I never use the downloads feature and forgot to keep it updated. I jus assume everyone will clone the repo. :) Version 0.4.3 is up there now: [Downloads](https://github.com/unscriptable/curl/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only doing normal javascript file loading (not modules), as it appears, i would encourage you to check out LABjs (http://labjs.com). LABjs focuses on being the most performance optimized loading solution (to the exclusion of some other features like module/dependency style stuff).

In fact, LABjs 2.0a (https://github.com/getify/LABjs/blob/master/next/LAB.src.js), which will be fully released in the next few days, is really exceptionally fast (even more than 1.2) at loading general scripts in parallel. I encourage you to give it a try, unless (as John eludes to above) you plan to go to module syntax... then stick with Curl or RequireJS.

Comment: Actually, LabJS is one of the items I'm evaluating. Additionally, I do plan on loading modules, as well.  However, I'm still trying to get my head wrapped around the whole CommonJS and AMD thing and Curl is the first one I'm looking at...which is why I posted this.

Comment: You may want to have someone create a LabJS tag on StackOverflow so questions can be better grouped.

Comment: @Prisoner -- good suggestion, done now. went and tagged a bunch of old posts with the new "labjs" tag.